# How to make the video appear on html

Tags: html

I am trying to play a video on HTML using video tag. However, it is not playing at all. I'm thinking maybe it is the path problem.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/dcAa4.jpg "screenshot of the file path"

I tried to use multiple video formats like WebM, mp4, and avi to test it out. However, the result is the same.

```
<video width="420" height="345" src="../test.mp4">
                    </video>
```

Comment: The path of the video depends on the path the browser is currently pointing to, not on where your template file is.

Comment: Change it to `<video controls width="420"...` Are you now able to get it to play?

Comment: did you try the first example : https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_video.asp

Comment: Why is `test.mp4` red in your IDE? None of the other files are, and it makes me wonder if the file's been deleted from your repository.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this. video inside source tag. In your code you are miss controls. Html video can not play automatically. so we need control

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html> 
    <html> 
    <body> 

    <video width="400" controls>
      <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
<video width="400" controls src="../video.mp4"></video>
    </body> 
    </html>
```